# How to write into a temporary file from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to write into a temporary file (in the temp folder of a machine) from a Rails app, I am using `Spreadsheet::Workbook.new` and I want the contents to be written into a temp file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Ruby's [`Tempfile`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html):

```
file = Tempfile.new('prefix')
```

or with a block:

```
Tempfile.new('prefix') do |file|
  # do the work with the file
end
```

Comment: file = Tempfile.new(%w[f .xls])

Comment: book.write(file)